# Bubbles Graph \ injecting pictures insead of bubbles

Tags: c#, java, open-source, graph, bubble-chart

I'm looking for a graph API (open source or to buy) - that enables to draw bubbles graph from input data - but the twist is that I want the bubbles to be pictures (gif,JPEG etc.) that I'll inject (instead of bubbles) - and the pictures will be in the size of the bubble (some pictures will be relatively small others are relatively big according to the input data).

Is there such kit?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [eboix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1063041/eboix) comments, [`org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYBubbleRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBubbleRenderer.html) would be a good starting point, although you'd have to override [`drawItem()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBubbleRenderer.html#line.155).

Comment: Thanks for both of you!  I'll look into that. other suggestions will be appreciated.